# How can you declare that an ASP .NET Web API action parameter must be non-null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple action like the one below, is there a way to declare that thingy must not be null, and if it is, ModelState.IsValid would be false? Or should every action also be checking for a null thingy?

```
        public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething(Thingy thingy)
        {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 // We never get here if thingy is null
             }
        }
```

Comment: Can you just put a simple `if(thingy != null && ModelState.IsValue)`?

Comment: Certainly, but I am somewhat confused as to why this wouldn't be part of the generated code if it was in fact a good practice or part of the pattern? I am wondering if there is a way to make ModelState.IsValid only true if the param is != null. If checking for null is the answer, that's fine, but it seems like a major flaw in the VS 2012 controller code generation template, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Since `thingy` is null, that means MVC wasn't able to bind the data you delivered to the action to the class of `Thingy`. So in that case, `ModelState` isn't sure what model to validate against, thus giving it a green light. How are you delivering data to the action?

Comment: First, I'm intentionally passing *no* data, not incorrectly formatted data. This is more of a philosophical question, I'm using AJAX and JSON. I'm not having problems, I am just intentionally testing a null scenario to see what happens when a developer abuses my API. I am very confused why ModelState would assume a green light if it can't figure out what model to validate against. This seems very optimistic. To my mind, if nothing is passed in, how in the world can the model be valid?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is open source. Take a look at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1fa5fe9ce17f#src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelStateDictionary.cs which shows that `IsValid` just checks to see if there are any validation errors. Unless there's a model to validate against, `IsValid` will always return true.